# JavaScript get array size efficiency

Tags: javascript, c++

I read the following from w3schools [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_performance.asp)

```
Bad Code:
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

Better Code:
l = arr.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
```

I was taught C++ and Java in school and I never learnt that this is something we need to consider for efficiency. Isn't getting the size of array just a O(1) operation? Is this optimization really necessary and is it really what people do in industry?

EDIT:

Given that the array's size won't change.

Comment: In the old days it mattered, in current JS engines it makes no difference.

Comment: It's a micro-optimization -- in the first instance, `arr.length` must be recalculated each time you pass through the loop. For small loops, it's completely unnoticeable.

Comment: @0x499602D2 please elaborate - if anything it's _more_ useful in JS than in other languages

Comment: @Alnitak I agreed right after you mentioned the array length could change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, getting the length is O(1), but it's not *typically* optimised out because it's feasible for the array length to change during the loop.

In the case where I know the array length won't change my preferred syntax is:

```
for (var i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; ++i)
```

As usual, w3schools misses the point - the first version they quote isn't *always* bad code, because that code might be exactly what's required if the array length is modified during the loop.

Comment: It's also better habit to write the loop in the manner.  Not all stopping conditions are going to be trivial to calculate.

Comment: So even if I know the size of  array won't change, I should not call arr.length every time?

Comment: @Arch1tect it might make a _tiny_ bit of difference to performance, but why evaluate a loop invariant for every pass of the loop if you don't have to?

Comment: I agree it's slightly faster, I just feel that it's such tiny improvement that I shouldn't need to change the way I used to write for loops..

Comment: so don't - but in any event it's _always_ better to move any loop invariants outside of the loop.

Comment: yep, fair  enough  :)